# Ubuntu 22.04: failing to build pdf due to makeindex -s python.ist

Tags: latex, python-sphinx

I try to build the pdf version of the documentaation using Ubuntu 22.04, texlive schema basic. I installed all the missing styles and the procedure get close to final but I get

```
Running 'makeindex -s python.ist  -o "aprieoe10.ind" "aprieoe10.idx"'
Index style file python.ist not found.
```

The file python.ist IS in the folder where building happens and if I use

```
makeindex -s ./python.ist  -o "aprieoe10.ind" "aprieoe10.idx"
```

it manages to build. What am I getting wrong in my install? Is there any path I need to specify?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: `makeindex -s python.ist -o ...` works for me. I don't know how to reproduce the problem.